# Does Wall of Fire get to deal its damage twice (minimum), when normal creatures are trapped within the circle?

Tags: dnd-5e, wall

Let's say a character casts [Wall of Fire](https://www.dndbeyond.com/spells/wall-of-fire) in the ring shape, choosing the inside of the wall as the side that does damage. A creature is inside the ring.

When the spell is first cast, the creature must make a Dex save or take 5d8 damage. Then, on the creature's turn, it wants to move out of the ring, and it will need make another Dex save as it moves through the wall. Effectively, a single casting will require a creature inside the ring to make a minimum of 2 saves in a normal movement situation. Correct?

Note: I realize by the time characters are level 7+, there are many ways to avoid the second Dex save, including flying over the wall, burrowing under the wall, teleporting out, casting a barrier spell within the ring, being immune to fire, etc. I'm just asking about normal movement situations without other tricks, to ensure I've understood the spell. Thanks!

Comment: Related (possibly duplicates): [Ringed Wall of Fire: How does the damage sequence go?](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/47966/ringed-wall-of-fire-how-does-the-damage-sequence-go), [How does damage work when entering a Wall of Fire?](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/164599/how-does-damage-work-when-entering-a-wall-of-fire)

Comment: Sorry I missed that! I searched for "Wall of Fire" and somehow didn't find that question. Thanks for the link!

Comment: A link to your related followup question: [After a creature makes a Dex save from Wall of Fire, does it end up inside or outside the ring?](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/166251/after-a-creature-makes-a-dex-save-from-wall-of-fire-does-it-end-up-inside-or-ou)

Comment: Thank you, @V2Blast ! I'm learning the ropes... I'll do that myself next time. :)