# After a creature makes a Dex save from Wall of Fire, does it end up inside or outside the ring?

Tags: dnd-5e, spells, area-of-effect, wall

Let's say a Wizard casts [Wall of Fire](https://www.dndbeyond.com/spells/wall-of-fire) in the ring shape, choosing the inside of the wall as the side that does damage.

An enemy is in one of the squares on the edge of the ring (ie. one of the 8 squares on the outside of the template for a 20' diameter circle, and not the 4 inner squares). Therefore, the enemy must make a Dex save and might take 5d8 damage.

If it makes the save, is it inside the ring?

If it fails the save, is it inside the ring?

Here is a good reference for the way the damage works: [Ringed Wall of Fire: How does the damage sequence go?](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/47966/ringed-wall-of-fire-how-does-the-damage-sequence-go)

Comment: Related: [Does the Wall of Fire spell damage creatures on both sides of the wall?](/questions/145509/does-the-wall-of-fire-spell-damage-creatures-on-both-sides-of-the-wall), [How does damage work when entering a Wall of Fire?](/questions/164599/how-does-damage-work-when-entering-a-wall-of-fire), [How much damage does a creature take for spending its entire turn inside a Wall of Fire?](/questions/138743/how-much-damage-does-a-creature-take-for-spending-its-entire-turn-inside-a-wall)

Answer (score 11):

### Creatures do not move when making a saving throw against *wall of fire*

The [*wall of fire*](https://www.dndbeyond.com/spells/wall-of-fire) spell states:

> [...] When the wall appears, each creature within its area must make a Dexterity saving throw. On a failed save, a creature takes 5d8 fire damage, or half as much damage on a successful save [...]

One thing we know is that [spells do only what they say they do](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/107637) and *wall of fire* does not say that creatures move after attempting (succeeding *or* failing) its saving throw. Thus they do not move.

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/105528/discussion-on-answer-by-medix2-after-a-creature-makes-a-dex-save-from-wall-of-fi).

Comment: So just to clarify the answer: Any creature that was literally touching the ring of fire when the spell was cast, is still literally touching the ring of fire when its turn starts. That seems reasonable to me.

I have no idea why you mention an odd shape and reference another question, which muddies your answer. I recommend removing that part of the answer. Either way, thanks for the reply!